# Replace with quotes in Java

Tags: java, html, replace

I receive from internet-service html code:

String html = Service.getHtml();

In html i have for example:

```
<div style="text"></div>
```

i would like use in replace 'style="text"' to for example 'new="aaa"':

```
String new = html.replace("style=\"test\"", "new=\"aaa\"");
```

but this not working. It probably did not find the text with backslash.

Comment: [Obligatory link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2071828). Although not Regex, this is still a bad idea. Use an HTML parser like [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/).

Comment: I would have solved this immediately if you said anything regarding what was not working besides "this is not working."

Comment: What *does* "not working" mean? Is that the *exact* code? Does it result in a *compiler error*? If not, what happens to make it "not work"?

Comment: Assuming that the OP copied the code, I believe he made the a spelling mistake: `html.replace("style=\"test\"", "new=\"aaa\"");` --> `html.replace("style=\"text\"", "new=\"aaa\"");`

Answer (score 0):

A problem is that `new` is a keyword in Java - you can't use it as a variable name! - and the posted code will not compile.

Comment: @user2864740 yes it does. what are you talking about?

Comment: @djechlin Assuming that the question is "why doesn't this compile?", perhaps. But I am not an Oracle.

Comment: @djechlin that's fine, if user2864740 thinks this answer is not useful I'm okay with his downvote :)

Comment: @user2864740 poor you, this guy figured out that was exactly the problem, posted an answer, and now you're downvoting because you aren't the OP and don't actually see what the problem is. What you just said describes why it's a terrible *question*. I think these two downvotes are absurd but I'm not upvoting because I rather strongly feel it's a disservice to all parties involved to answer such awful questions.

Comment: @user2864740 s/^/The problem is that / should fix this answer for you.

Comment: @djechlin your suggestion sounds reasonable, wording issue is now fixed.

Comment: @user2864740 btw, if can compile `String new = html.replace("style=\"test\"", "new=\"aaa\"");` in Java - I'm taking my hat off ;)

Comment: @djechlin Terrible questions (as in questions which do not explain, or worse, exhibit behavior other than that which is explained) should not be honored with answers; rather, clarification should be sought in comments.

Comment: @user2864740 I know it's debatable: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16621/how-to-handle-bad-questions-with-good-answers